# The method ngGetContentSelectors(), deprecated in Angular 4.0

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 4.0 the method `ngGetContentSelectors()`, is deprecated. Then which is the alternative for this.

Answer (score 0):

By reading Angular 5.0 changelog, it seems that you can use `ComponentFactory.ngContentSelectors` now.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes